# Can only a component field be refreshed after editing instead of refreshing the whole page?

Tags: adobe, aem

I have a requirement of refreshing only the area under the component which has been recently authored. I have tried with the existing listners configs in CQ but not able to achieve this. Can anyone help??

Comment: The component you are editing gets automatically refreshed after you close the dialog. Please elaborate what exactly your issue is?

Comment: Actually whenever we author a page using a component , the data gets saved into crx. We can attach a listner to the component cq:editconfig that may listen to particular event like afteredit etc and we can provide predifined actions like PAGE_REFRESH etc. but in my case , the component is saving the value into the crx , but the page does not show the new values until the page refresh. I dont want the whole page to be refreshed , just the component field.

Comment: As I said you don't need a listener as the component gets automatically refreshed after you edit it. You can see this if you for example monitor network with firebug. There is a ajax call to get a newly rendered version of the component you were editing. If this is not the case, there is something wrong with your component.

Answer (score 2):

Use REFRESH_SELF in _cq_editConfig.xml, it work's .